# how to see thread structure in .net?

Tags: .net, multithreading, visualization

Is this possible in .net to see visually ,thread structure those are running (in multithreading) ? if yes , how can i see that

Comment: How is it you are wanting to see the active threads? Programmatically, or debugging??? If debugging, which IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, attach the debugger to your program and see the Threads window (CTRL+D, T).

Comment: how to attach this window ? i m using VS2008. Is i need to download it from some where ?

Comment: No, you just need to start debugging (run your app in debug mode or go to Debug -> Attach to process... in the menu bar if your app is already running outside Visual Studio), and then press CTRL+D, T or go to Debug -> Windows -> Threads in the menu bar to show the Threads window.

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate there are a set of tools for visualizing the concurrency behavior of your application. See http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/220900288 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

to show the thread window in vs2008, you have to be debugging the application,

to attach just start your application in debug (press f5) or attach to the process running your app by pressing ctrl-alt-p

all this is accessible from the debug menu, and debug->windows menu

once you are attached, it will show you a list of thread, the one you are in will have a yellow arrow, you can put name on threads to help sort them out, just press f2 to rename

you can just frm one thread to another or also freeze them, and then thaw, when needed